# Where to download previous versions of R for mac?

Tags: r, cran

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old/index-old.html) we find 'old' versions of R (from `2.0.1` to `2.7.0`).

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) we can find the current version (`3.6.3`)

Where can we download the versions in between? (i.e. not the newest version, but not 'old')

Comment: Use this link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old/. There are more version there.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks very much. I thought your comment solved it, but alas I'm after `3.5.1`, and for some reason, it's not there. Any ideas? (I find it odd that all previous versions aren't provided, it's not like they take up a lot of space or anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old contains `dmg`, `pkg` and `tar.gz` files (thanks @MrFlick)

Source files can be found at
https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/ for 3.x
and 
https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/
for 2.x

Comment: What about 4.x versions?

Comment: Archived 4.x versions can be downloaded from https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/